# Non white space characters cannot be added to content when creating XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am creating a simple XML file here, and when I do I get this error about a non white space characters cannot be added to content.

In the constructor I passed a string to create the first node known as Root.  This causes the non white space error in the code. Does anyone see the problem.  This is C# on Visual Studio.

```
XDocument myDoc = new XDocument("Root");
            myDoc.Add(
           Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i =>

                            new XElement("Entry",
                                 new XAttribute("Address", "0123"),
                                 new XAttribute("default", "0"),

                            new XElement("Descripion", "here is the description"),
                            new XElement("Data", "Data goes here ")

                    )));

            myDoc.Save("foo.xml");
```

Comment: Should your range be (0,5) since you only have 5 elements?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it, but the compiler points to the problem when I create the instance of the class XDocument in the first line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is at this line

```
XDocument myDoc = new XDocument("Root");
```

Change your code as:

```
XElement root = new XElement("root");
XDocument myDoc = new XDocument(root);
root.Add( Enumerable.Range...... );

myDoc.Save("foo.xml");
```